# Hibernate error : unexpected end of subtree select TIMEDIFF

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

when I use the below query in mysql db, it returns me difference time.

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('2007-12-31 10:02:00','2007-12-30 12:01:01');
```

But when I use the same query in hibernate (hql), it throws me the below error

**Query :**

```
hql="SELECT TIMEDIFF('2007-12-31 10:02:00','2007-12-30 12:01:01')";

query = session.createQuery(hql);
```

**Error:**

```
unexpected end of subtree [SELECT TIMEDIFF('2007-12-31 10:02:00','2007-12-30 12:01:01')]
```

Can anybody let me know a solution on this to find the timedifference

Comment: what version of hibernate are you using?

Comment: and why would you like to timediff two values, which are obviously not stored in the database via hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HQL which works is

```
select

(days(current_timestamp) *24 + hour(current_timestamp)) -( days(user.lastUpdatedTimeStamp)*24 + hour( user.lastUpdatedTimeStamp))

from com.test.User as user where user.id=1;
```

This hql will give the correct answer as it will add the number of hours corresponding to the date to the number of hours on that particular date.

Mathematically, this will be like this

```
((19*24 + 11)  -(18*24 +5)) == 467 – 437 = 30
```

So, we will get the correct answer 30.

[This](http://www.coderanch.com/t/216833/ORM/databases/writing-HQL-query-date-calculation) might be usefull.